# std::ios_base::ate and std::ios_base::trunc

Tags: c++

What the point of the `std::ios_base::ate` (other than `std::ios_base::app`, for example) and `std::ios_base::trunc` (other than `std::ios_base::out`, for example)?

And should i preferly write `std::ios_base::smth` instead of `std::ios::smth`?

Comment: `std::ios_base::in` and `std::ios::in` should be identical, it's up to you.

Comment: @veer yes they are, as well as any::ios_base::descendant::in :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

std::ios_base::ate position the cursor at the end of the text whereas std::ios_base_app appends text (with a write operation) at the end, though you can still read from the beginning :)

std::ios_base::trunc truncates the file so it is emptied, whereas std::ios_base::out just specify you want to write to the stream.

I currently can't quote the standard (on my tablet and Acrobat Reader won't let met copy) but from paragraph 27.4.2.1.4 from ISO 14882:1998 the information you can see on the link is almost exact: http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/openmode/

To sum up:

```
std::ios_base::app = append
```

Append at the end of the stream by "seek[ing] to end before each write"

```
std::ios_base::ate = At The End
```

Open and seek immediately at the end after opening

```
std::ios_base::binary = binary
```

Perform operation in binary as opposed to text

```
std::ios_base::in = input
```

Open in read mode

```
std::ios_base::out = output
```

Open in write mode

```
std::ios_base::trunc = truncate
```

Truncate the stream on opening.

These values are just flags, so you can open a stream in read/write binary at the end with :

```
std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate | std::ios_base::binary
```

---

Concerning the way of using those values, it is as you wish. They are declared as public static fields in `std::ios_base` class (see 27.4.2) thus it is possible to access them using `std::ios::ate` or even something like `cout.binary` !

---

The points where you must take attention is that `std::ios_base::ate` does NOT imply `std::ios_base::app` nor does `std::ios_base::out` implies `std::ios_base::trunc`. Each field has a different meaning, and a different case of use, though most of them can't be used alone :)

Comment: But std::ios_base::out also clear the data in the file, no? Can you give me an example where std::ios_base::out don't clear the file?

Comment: From here : http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/openmode/ you get the definition of each value. Moreover, this answer @veer's comment about std::ios_base::in and std::ios::in

Comment: And what do you mean by "you can still read from the beginning"? Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: I mean that ios::ate positions the cursor at the end of the stream, so you can still move it around if you like (and if the stream isn't empty and permit it)

Comment: Why i can't do this with std::ios_base::app? I can use seekp also

Comment: std::ios_base::app seek to the end before each write operation