# ios_base::ate and cleaning file

Tags: c++

Help please, code execution outputs instead of

```
123456
```

just

```
456
```

Why the file is cleared before writing? Trunc not set

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream a{ "1.txt",ios_base::ate };
    a << "123";
    a.close();
    ofstream b{ "1.txt",ios_base::ate };
    b << "456";
    b.close();
    ifstream c{ "1.txt" };
    string str;
    c >> str;
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The file is rewritten every time

Comment: Simply read the documentation for the functions you use. The documentation is very clear about what they do. -1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `app` in your second writer to append the content to the file instead of rewritting it, as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream a{ "1.txt",ios_base::ate };
    a << "123";
    a.close();
    ofstream b{ "1.txt",ios_base::app }; //notice here is app instead of ate
    b << "456";
    b.close();
    ifstream c{ "1.txt" };
    string str;
    c >> str;
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253183/stdios-baseate-and-stdios-basetrunc) :

> std::ios_base::ate does NOT imply std::ios_base::app

So if you use `ate` it does not mean that it will append the content to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the different between `ios_base:ate` and `ios_base:app` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359702/c-filehandling-difference-between-iosapp-and-iosate)

For your code, you can change it like this:

```
ofstream b {"1.txt", ios_base:app};
```